# WPF ListView ItemTemplate too large space per Label

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, itemtemplate

I have a data bound ListView that uses a rather strange heights for every `ListViewItem` after I start using an `ItemTemplate`.

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllTvShows}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <Label FontStretch="Normal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Without the `ItemTemplate` the labels have the normal height (more adjacent). How should I specify the `Label` so that it would render normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a TextBlock instead of a Label:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllTvShows}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```